# Data display order when value matches SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to display data in a particular way. Now my data looks like -

```
ID  |   Name    |   NID
A1      test1       A201
B1      test2       null
C2      test3       null
A201    test1       null
```

But I want when `NID` value matches with `ID`, that matching `ID` value will display in the next row like below -

```
ID  |   Name    |   NID
A1      test1       A201
A201    test1       null
B1      test2       null
C2      test3       null
```

I was thinking to use an array to do this but did not work. I am not sure how can I achieve this. I have tried below -

```
declare @newID table (s_newID nvarchar(max))
insert @newID (s_newID) select NID from Table1 

select ID, Name, NID from Table1
order by
    case
        when NID IN (select s_newID from @newID) then 1 else 0
    end
```

Could someone please advise me how can I achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: If there's any possibility of *chains* (e.g. if `A201` had `C2` as `NID`, that should come after `A201` and before `B1`) then this cannot easily be done with just an `ORDER BY` clause. And what if two rows have the same `NID` value?

Comment: I guess at first you'll need to build a whole tree/list from linked rows. What if there are much more linked elements? What if A201 points to C2, C2 -> B1 and so on?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, there is no possibility that A201 have C2 as NID, NID always has one row

Comment: So, to be clear, with your data rules, each `NID` entry is unique and any row which appears as a `NID` entry will not, itself, have a `NID` entry. That's doable.

Comment: @IvanStarostin, NID always have only 1 linked element

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, Yes NID is unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select t1.ID, t1.Name, t1.NID
from Table1 t1
left join Table1 t2
on t1.ID = t2.NID
order by
    COALESCE(t2.ID,t1.ID),
    CASE WHEN t1.NID is not null THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

We use a `LEFT JOIN` to join to our referencing row if we're referenced as a `NID`. If we are, we use *that* row's ID as our primary sort condition rather than our own. For the secondary sort, we put items that have a `NID` value (but are otherwise equal to another row based on our primary sort) first.